# Python to Java convert problems

Tags: java, python

I tried convert from Python to Java but idk why its not working.

```
i = 0
e = input ('How much?')
a = ''
while not i == e:

if i % 2 == 1 and i % 3 == 1 and i % 4 == 1 and i % 5 == 1 and i % 6 == 1 and i % 7 == 0:
    a = a +str(i)+','
    i = i +1
    print i
else:
    i = i +1
    print i
   print 'Die Ergebnisse lauten:'
   print a
```

to Java

```
var i = 0;
var a = '';
var e = System.out.print("How much");

while (i !== e) {
 if (i % 2 == 1 & i % 3 == 1 & i % 4 == 1 & i % 5 == 1 & i % 6 == 1 & i % 7 == 0){
     a = a + System.out.print(i);
     i++;
     System.out.print(i);
   } else {
       i++;
       System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Idk whats wrong?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Hi! Can you provide us with what "not working" means? Is there an error (and what is it)? Is the output different from what you are expecting (what are you expecting?) etc.

Comment: A single ampersand is not the right conditional you want. Use `&&`

Comment: first thing i notice is `while not i == e:` comparing the values but  `while (i !== e)`  is comparing the value and the type , shouldn't it be `while (i != e)` ?

Comment: `int i`, `String a` and `int e` must be readed using Scanner or BufferedReader.

Comment: Note that Java 10 added *local variable type inference* and uses `var` as a keyword.  The above could be a Java fragment and not JavaScript. http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286

Comment: Why can't you use `Integer.parseInt` ?

Comment: That is new for me @markspace, thanks!

Comment: @markspace But `var a = ''` would create a character, not a string I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The Java code should be something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int i = 0;
int e = Integer.parseInt(br.readline('How much?'));
String a = "";
while (i != e) {
 if ( i % 2 == 1 && i % 3 == 1 && i % 4 == 1 && i % 5 == 1 && i % 6 == 1 && i % 7 == 0) {
    a += i + ",";
    i++;
   System.out.println(i);
 } else {
   i++;
   System.out.println(i);
   System.out.println("Die Ergebnisse lauten:"); 
   System.out.println(a);
 }
}
```

If somebody view any problem comment this please, I write this from my phone.